# When to use #import & when @class - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have already created a class named "Category"

In some online examples I have seen - they have implemented #import "Category.h"

In some examples - class in pre declared like @category before @interface new class

So I am confused 
=> When to use #import &
=> When to use @class?